# How can my modelstate be invalid when there are no constraints on it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class BookingViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }        
    public DateTime CheckInDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckOutDate { get; set; }
    
    //Need this to display which room was chosen by the user
    public RoomTypeDTO? RoomType { get; set; }
    public int RoomTypeId { get; set; }

}
```

The view looks (partly) like this:

```
    <div>
        <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>
        <input asp-for="FirstName" class="col-xs-4"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <br />
     <div>
        <label asp-for="LastName"></label>
        <input asp-for="LastName" class="col-xs-4" />
        <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div>.......
```

When the ViewModel is sent from this view to the controller action Create, if I don't input anything in FirstName and LastName textboxes, I get invalid modelstate and then the default errors "First Name is required"

How can this be happening? It's conflicting with my fluent validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, non-nullable types are treated as-if they are decorated with the `[Required]` attribute.

From the docs [Non-nullable reference types and the [Required] attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#non-nullable-reference-types-and-the-required-attribute):

> The validation system treats non-nullable parameters or bound
> properties as if they had a [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
> attribute. By enabling Nullable contexts, MVC implicitly starts
> validating non-nullable properties on non-generic types or parameters
> as if they had been attributed with the [Required(AllowEmptyStrings =
> true)] attribute. Consider the following code:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

> If the app was built with enable, a missing value
> for Name in a JSON or form post results in a validation error. Use a
> nullable reference type to allow null or missing values to be
> specified for the Name property:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

> This behavior can be disabled by configuring
> [SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcoptions.suppressimplicitrequiredattributefornonnullablereferencetypes?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-mvcoptions-suppressimplicitrequiredattributefornonnullablereferencetypes) in
> Program.cs:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers(
    options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true);
```

Comment: But why is this overriding my fluent validation?

RuleFor(x => x.FirstName)
.NotNull()
.WithMessage("{PropertyName} input is required!")
.Length(2, 25)
.WithMessage("{PropertyName} length must be between 2-25!")
.Matches(@"^[a-zA-Z-']*$")
.WithMessage("{PropertyName} must contain only letters A-Z");

I am not getting the message from WithMessage. Why is that? I am getting the other messages.

I have another application with almost identical code and the properties even look the same, i.e. they are not string? but just string... but I still get the right error message.

Comment: Also, suppressing the required attribute worked. But is that recommended?

Comment: That's a good question, re: overriding your fluent validation. I'm not entirely sure, but would surmise the asp.net validation is taking precedence over the fluent validation. I'd recommend heading over to the fluent validation's github issues and ask over there.

Comment: As for is suppressing the default required attributes in a non-nullable context, that's really something you have to determine. However, I believe the suppression is correct for your use case as you will be using fluent-validation.